# where solr store search index, in database or in file?

Tags: search, indexing, solr

I am new to Solr. can anybody tell where it stores index.

1. in existing site database
2. create new database
3. into xml files.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** i am asking this because i need a list of files to copy over to production. 
Suppose, if i index a site on development environment, which files i need to copy over to production environment. we dont want to re-index whole site again when its live.

**EDIT-2** where i can find index directory, which stores data folder?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solr (and underlying Lucene) index is a specially designed data structure,
stored on the file system as a set of index files.

The index is designed with efficient data structures to maximize performance and minimize resource usage.

you can check the lucene index usually residing in the data/index folder

Detailed info @ http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/fileformats.html

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, so if i index a site on development environment, which files i need to copy over to production environment. we dont want to re-index whole site again when its live.

Comment: you can copy over the data folder which holds the index directory.

Comment: yes, thats what i am asking, where i can find index directory. i am using debian environment

Comment: is this would be solr/data/index ?

Comment: yes should be .... it usually is where you have the conf directory where conf files (schema.xml and solrconfig.xml) defined.